# Bijection between $[0,1]$ and $K$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The following map $f:[0,1]\to K$. let $x=0.x_1 x_2 x_3\dots$ be the binary rep of $x$ in $[0,1]$ then $f(x)= 0.(2x_1)(2x_2)(2x_3)\dots$ in scale 3 ,then $f(x)$ is in $K$. If we consider a unique binary rep of $x$ earlier I think $f$ is $1-1$. Is the map $f$ bijection between $[0,1]$ and $K$?

Comment: Sorry, K is Cantor set.

Comment: Why (how) is $f(x)$ in $K$? ($0.(2x_1)(2x_2)\dots$ is just $2\cdot0.x_1x_2\dots$, right? so $f(x)=2x$)

Comment: @Ragnar This refers to the ternary expansion (but I agree that the formulation of the question should be seriously modified--not to mention some personal input from the OP).

Comment: @Did Then, I see why it would make sense, but that could be more clear indeed.

Comment: No no. In binary rep of x  each x_i(i th binary digit) is either 0 or 1 f maps in such a way it changes each binary digit to twice i.e changing the digits 1 to 2 only. Now take it as a ternary rep of a point of K.f(x)= sum (2x_n/3^n).

Comment: Yes yes, that is exactly the conclusion we arrived at. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: I am not comfortable in editing the question. Though I think it is clear now. Please help.

Comment: What are the pre-images of $1/3$ and $2/3$?

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation, what does K stand for?

Comment: for 1/3(=.000000 in scale 3) preimage is 0, for 2/3(.200000 in scale 3)  0.10000......

Comment: K = Cantor set.

Comment: $1/3\ne0$. $1/3$ is $0.1=0.0\overline2$ in base $3$.

Comment: Why do you insist in omitting the definition of K? You even erased it from a previous version... And since you seem actually pretty "comfortable in editing the question", I reiterate my suggestion: rewrite the thing to reach an acceptable version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $x$ does not have a unique binary representation if it terminates in binary.  Let $x=0.1000_2=0.01111\dots_2$  Then you can have $f(x)=0.2_3$ or $0.0222222\dots_3=0.1_3$, but not both.  One of them will not be in the range of $f$  This can be patched up.  There are only countably many of them, but this simple $f$ does not quite work.

Comment: I know x in[0,1] does not have unique binary representation. But make first a initial agreement about taking just one representation probably avoiding non terminating expressions. Then what will happen?

Comment: The point is that choosing one representation leaves a hole.  There is a (countable infinity of) point(s) in the "range" that doesn't have a preimage because we sent the number that should have been the preimage somewhere else.  I only showed one, but all the [dyadic fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) are in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the question that you had wanted to ask ;)

Let $N$ be the set of positive integers and $\{0,1\}^N$ the set of all $0$-$1$-sequences. Then the map
\begin{align*}
\{0,1\}^N&\to K\\
x&\mapsto 2\cdot 0.\,x_1x_2x_3\ldots_3
\end{align*}
is a bijection and the map 
\begin{align*}
\{0,1\}^N&\to [0,1]\\
x&\mapsto 0.\,x_1x_2x_3\ldots_2
\end{align*}
is a surjection. It follows that
$$\lvert[0,1]\rvert\le \lvert\{0,1\}^N\rvert = \lvert K\rvert \le \lvert[0,1]\rvert
$$
(the last because $K\subset[0,1]$) and hence
$$\lvert[0,1]\rvert= \lvert\{0,1\}^N\rvert = \lvert K\rvert
.$$